# Ruby on Rails + Amoeba Gem: undefined method 'macro'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, clone, amoeba-gem

I tried amoeba version 2.0.0 in the Rails console (with Ruby 2.1). This is my model:

```
class Dict < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :idioms, through: :cards
end
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dict
  has_many :idioms, dependent: :destroy
  amoeba do
    exclude_field :dict_id
  end
end
class Idiom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  amoeba do
    include_field :repres
    include_field :card_id
    include_field :kind
    include_field :note
  end
end
```

Now in the Rails console I try

```
c=Card.find_by_id(19) # yields a Card object
c.amoeba_dup
```

This raises the exception

```
NoMethodError: undefined method macro' for nil:NilClass
from .../amoeba-2.0.0/lib/amoeba.rb:412:in amo_process_association'
from .../amoeba-2.0.0/lib/amoeba.rb:381:in block in amoeba_dup'
from .../amoeba-2.0.0/lib/amoeba.rb:379:in each'
from ..../amoeba-2.0.0/lib/amoeba.rb:379:in amoeba_dup'
from .../amoeba-2.0.0/lib/amoeba.rb:457:in block in amo_process_association'
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on GitHub: [When using amoeba_dub : undefined method for NilClass](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba/issues/36)

It was caused by `include_field` being used on something that wasn't an association. Don't do that! To avoid ambiguity in the future, `include_field` was renamed to `include_association`.